# PsExec will copy the .exe but won't let me pass arguments to it

Tags: windows, deployment, pstools

This command copies the program test.exe to the remote system and executes it interactively:

```
psexec \\marklap -c test.exe
```

However I need to pass some arguments to the `text.exe` program.

This doesn't work:

```
psexec \\marklap -c "test.exe /S"
```

Answer (score 11):

I figured it out. You need to quote the .exe part and then just put the arguments for it after it:

```
psexec \\marklap -c "test.exe" /S
```

Comment: Otherwise PsExec thinks it's one file name with spaces in it, which makes sense after some thought. Good catch!